# redirect to file without extension instead of directory

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess

I have a htaccess file that I use for removing the file extension. It is working really nice except for one thing. In my root folder I have a file called dogs.html and a folder called dogs. When I write localhost:8081/dogs it gives me a 403 error. I want it to show the dogs.html. It works perfectly with my other files in my root folder.

This is my code:

`Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403-forbidden.html
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404-not-found.html
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ $1.html [L]`

What I want is when typing localhost:8081/dogs I want to be redirected to localhost:8081/dogs.html without need to add extension to address bar.

This is my directory structure:
`root
 | -- css(folder)
 |     | -- dogs(folder)
 |     |      | -- dog.css
 |     |
 |     | -- dogs.css
 |     | -- contact.css
 |
 | -- dogs(folder)
 |      | -- dog1.html
 |      | -- dog2.html
 |
 | -- dogs.html
 | -- contact.html`

dog1 and dog2 uses the same css file(dog.css)

When the extension is removed it thinks I mean the folder and because I have turned off indexing it throws a 403 error.

Comment: You’re excluding existing directories from rewriting via the RewriteCond and the `!-d` flag – therefor the request does not get rewritten, and since you denied directory listing using `Options -Indexes`, you get a 403.

Comment: @CBroe I removed the line with !-d and now it is showing the html file correctly but only the html file. The css do not seem to be included.

Comment: How are you referring to your CSS in your HTML document? What is the directory structure?

Comment: @CBroe I use a link tag in the header to referr to my css. For directory structure see edit above.